# Require .js file into my angular controller

Tags: angularjs, npm, browserify, resampling

I have a resampler.js file which does audio resampling. This file requires 2 other .js files:

var WebAudioLoader = require('webaudioloader');

var WavEncoder = require("wav-encoder");

I want to use this resampler in my angular controller like:

resampler(URL, 192000, function (event) { });

When i run my app i get the error: require is not defined

I read about the browserify library which lets include npm libraries for the browser but I am still unable to make it work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think http://requirejs.org/ could solve your error.

Comment: Requirejs enables to load those js files but my problem is that I need to use the require syntax inside my controller's code and there is where i get the error because the browser doesn't recognize the 'require'.

Comment: Browserify is what you want. "I am still unable to make it work" what have you tried so far?